# How to check column value among all others values in same column in Pandas Data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which having three columns.   Normally for the Loan type it has 5 values. Let's say Conso, Immo, Pro, Autre, Tous. For this data frame only contain loan type 'Immo'. (At the beginning we don't know what the Loan type is). How do I check what the loan type is among all this loan type?

```
CodeProduit  LoanType   Year
301          Immo       2003
301          Immo       2004
301          Immo       2005
301          Immo       2006
...          ...        ....
301          Immo       2017

def check_type_pret(p):
    if p == 'Immo':
         return p
    elif p == 'Conso':
        return p
    elif p == 'Pro':
        return p
    elif p == 'Autres':
        return p
    elif p == 'Tous':
        return p
    else:
        return 0



df1['Answer']=df1.LoanType.map(check_type_pret)
```

As a output I'm getting 0 for Answer Column. How do I get expected out put as I explained?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me: `df1['Answer']` ends up being `Immo` in each row.

Answer (score 1):

If want check if exist all values in `L` in column `LoanType` use:

```
L = ['Immo', 'Conso', 'Pro', 'Autres', 'Tous']
a = all([(df['LoanType'] == x).any() for x in L])
print (a)
False
```

Or:

```
s = set(['Immo', 'Conso', 'Pro', 'Autres', 'Tous'])
a = s.issubset(set(df['LoanType'].tolist()))
print (a)
False
```

EDIT:

If your solution return `0` there is no match.

I guess some traling whitespaces, so need remove them first by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df1['Answer'] = df1.LoanType.str.strip().map(check_type_pret)
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) and condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df1)
   CodeProduit LoanType  Year
0          301    Immo1  2003
1          301    Conso  2004
2          301      Pro  2005
3          301   Autres  2006
4          301     Tous  2017

df1.LoanType = df1.LoanType.str.strip()

L = ['Immo', 'Conso', 'Pro', 'Autres', 'Tous']
df1['Answer'] = np.where(df1.LoanType.isin(L), df1.LoanType, 0)
#another solution
#df1['Answer'] = df1.LoanType.where(df1.LoanType.isin(L),  0)
print (df1)
   CodeProduit LoanType  Year  Answer
0          301    Immo1  2003       0
1          301    Conso  2004   Conso
2          301      Pro  2005     Pro
3          301   Autres  2006  Autres
4          301     Tous  2017    Tous
```